# .replace() not working to remove <strong> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am using jquery to get the html content of a div, remove the strong tags and then update the div with the new contents though. It isn't working for some reason though. Here is my code:

```
var content = $('#mydivid').html();
content = content.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '');
$('#mydivid').html(content);
```

Anyone know why this isnt working?

Comment: maybe you have `<  ____ strong >`  ????

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/7RtAt/ -- does your code need to be inside a `$(document).ready` block?

Comment: Incidentally, you can replace both opening and closing tags at once using a regular expression: `.replace(/<\/?strong>/g, '')`

Answer (score 2):

First put in an alert to check content...

```
alert(content);
```

if that works then I would def not use replaceWith, try...

```
$('#mydivid').html(content);
```

Comment: Tried that, content just equals the html with strong tags still in place so the replace functions arent working for some reason

Comment: @geoffs3310: So what is the exact value of content.. with extra spaces etc.

Answer (score 2):

first:

you don't need to replace twice, the first argument of replace() is regex, so you can :

```
content.replace(/<\/?strong>/g, "");
```

to remove all the `<strong>` and `</strong>` label.

second:

`replaceWith()` is not what you want, `html()` is your target.

and this is all you want:

```
$(function() {
    $("#mydivid").html(function() {
        return $(this).html().replace(/<\/?strong>/g, "");
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pS5Xp/

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use replaceWith. You should update the div with the new content by calling .html() again:

```
var content = $('#mydivid').html();
content = content.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '');
$('#mydivid').html(content);
```

Works fine when I test it - http://jsbin.com/ihokav/edit#preview

A nicer alternative is to use replaceWith on the strong tags themselves:

```
$('#mydivid strong').replaceWith(function() { return $(this).html(); });
```

http://jsbin.com/ihokav/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

the only issue I can see with the code is that you are replacing the div iteself. You probably want to do this instead:-

```
var content = $('#mydivid').html();
content = content.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '');
$('#mydivid').html(content);
```

Also make sure you have lower case strong tags.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/8pVdw/

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = $('#mydivid').html();

$('#mydivid').html(content.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', ''));
```

Should work.

If it doesn't, just alert the contents and see if it works.

Comment: Please style code by selecting the code then clicking the { } button. Makes it a tad easier to read:-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var div = $('#mydivid');
var strong = div.find("strong");
strong.replaceWith(strong.text());
```

What this does is just finds the `<strong>` tag and replaces it with the text contents.
A fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cWpUK/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Syntax:
 * Node replaceNode(Node newNode, Node oldNode)
 * Node replaceNode(String newNode, Node oldNode)
 * Node replaceNode(Object newNode, Node oldNode)
 * - newNode: { String localName [, String namespaceURI ] }
 * null replaceNode(null newNode, Node oldNode)
 * - will delete the old node and move all childNodes to the parentNode
 **/

// nodes from another document has to be imported first
// should throw an Error if newNode is descendant-or-self
// type of newNode is tested by 'firstChild' (DOM 1)
// returns new Node
var replaceNode = (function() {
    var replaceNode = function(newNode, oldNode) {
        var document = oldNode.ownerDocument;
            if(newNode === null)
                newNode = document.createDocumentFragment();
            else if(typeof newNode === 'string' || newNode instanceof String)
                newNode = {localName: newNode};
            if(!('firstChild' in newNode)) {
                var namespaceURI = 'namespaceURI' in newNode ?
                    newNode.namespaceURI : replaceNode.namespaceURI;
                newNode = namespaceURI === null ?
                    document.createElement(newNode.localName) :
                    document.createElementNS(namespaceURI, newNode.localName);
            }
            var parentNode = oldNode.parentNode,
                nextSibling = oldNode.nextSibling;
            parentNode.removeChild(oldNode);
            if(newNode.nodeType === 1 || newNode.nodeType === 11)
                while(oldNode.firstChild)
                    newNode.appendChild(oldNode.firstChild);
            parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, nextSibling);
            return newNode.nodeType === 11 ? null : newNode;
    };
    replaceNode.namespaceURI = null;
    return replaceNode;
})();
```

This will replace a Node with another one. This has the advantage that no EventListeners on subsequent Nodes are destroyed.

```
var nodeList = document.getElementById('mydivid').getElementsByTagName('strong');
while(nodeList.length)
    replaceNode(null, nodeList[ nodeList.length - 1 ]);
```

[Testcase](http://jsfiddle.net/7rRca/4/)