# remove parent tag <strong> from child tag <a>

Tags: javascript

I want in JavaScript to remove `<strong>` tag with function: `myfunc(this)`

```
<strong><a href="#" onclick="myfunc(this)">mylink</a></strong>
```

I do want to clean the code, so only `<strong>` tag is needed to be removed

Comment: You said you want to "remove tag with function: myfunc(this)" (which is the `<a>`) but then you say "only strong tag is needed to be removed" (which is the `<strong>`). What do you actually want to do?

Comment: It would be easier to set/remove `font-weight: bold` on the `<a>` tag itself. Are you using `<strong>  for its semantic purpose or just for printing bold?

Comment: @sircapsalot wouldn't that remove the anchor itself?

Comment: With this.parent.remove() doesn't it remove also the <a>? :|

Comment: Clean the code in javascript? Why bother? It will have already been rendered, this would just force the browser to re-render.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891272/replace-not-working-to-remove-strong-tags?rq=1

Comment: @nullability What do you mean? Changing the markup with JS won't cause the browser to refresh if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do exactly that:

```
function myfunc(node)
{
    node.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(node, node.parentNode);
}
```

The problem is that it can only be run once, so you need an additional check:

```
function myfunc(node)
{
    var parent = node.parentNode;

    if (parent.nodeName === 'STRONG') {
        parent.parentNode.replaceChild(node, parent);
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/amofuf/1/)

Comment: To make it exactly as I need, i just added a little more code: if(node.parentNode.tagName=="STRONG")

Comment: @Jigberto I already have that condition in my code :)

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer could be (supposing you only have the `<a>` inside the `<strong>` element)

```
function myfunc(e) {
    var oStrong = e.parentNode;
    oStrong.parentNode.appendChild(e);
    oStrong.parentNode.removeChild(oStrong);
}
```

However, I'd also like to point out the difference between `<strong>` and what could - mistakenly - be used as a synonim: the `<b>` attribute, or its cousin, the `style.fontWeight = 'bold';` css attribute.

`<strong>` is meant to emphasize an *important text*, and will be interpreted as such by browsers for blind people for example. The bold aspect is purely a style and won't render under lynx.

So, if you want to make something bold, use the css style mentionned above instead. You could then easily remove this style by just calling `.style.fontWeight = 'normal';`

Comment: +1 for information about accessibility considerations

Answer (score 1):

This is also a possible solution, that would take into consideration any other nodes that were also children of `strong`.

HTML

```
<div>
    <strong>saker <a id="link1" href="#">mylink</a> ting</strong>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunc() {
    this.removeEventListener("click", myFunc);

    var copyNodeList = [],
        parent = this.parentNode,
        grandParent = parent.parentNode;

    while (parent.firstChild) {
        copyNodeList.push(parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild));
    }

    grandParent.removeChild(parent);

    copyNodeList.forEach(function (node) {
        grandParent.appendChild(node);
    });
}

document.getElementById("link1").addEventListener("click", myFunc, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7w2xF/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunc(obj) {
    if ($(obj).parent().is("strong")) {
        $(obj).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function myfunc(elem){ 
          $(elem).parent().html($(elem)); 
}
```